# Beet leaves bubbling

Tags: leaves, pest-damage, beetroot

A few of my beet plants (~5%) have these odd skin-like bubbles forming on one or two of their leaves.  When I pop them they're filled with these patches of black particles (possibly dead pests of some sort?).  Any ideas what they're from, and/or if they're malicious?

I'm in the high desert in Albuquerque, NM where it's been oscillating between intense sun, cool (40s-50sF) nights, and spotty rain.  I have had an outbreak of leaf miners on the beet leaves and nearby on some cauliflower and spinach leaves.  Could this be related?

[image: Top of the leaf]
[image: Back of the leaf]
[image: Top after popping]

Comment: Something similar happened here: [Beet Leaves turning yellow brown](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/25106/beet-plant-leaves-turning-yellow-brown)

Comment: Yeah I looked through that before posting, but I didn't find any reference to bubbling like this.  I'll cut back on the watering a bit (I may be overcompensating for the dry, windy, and sunny conditions) and try the Boron though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be spinach leaf miners - they're a pest on beets as well. The blisters are caused by the tiny maggots inside the leaf, that's likely what the black bits are that you can see now  you've popped a blister.

There's no real solution other than trying to keep them out in the first place by using row covers or something similar - more info here http://www.apartmenttherapy.com/gardening-qa-why-are-my-swiss-153766